# Missing checkboxes to start/stop server JVM (IBM WebSphere)

Tags: websphere-7

on a WebSphere 7.0 console under Servers -> Server Types -> WebSphere application servers I do not see the checkboxes next to JVM servers. The version is **ND 7.0.0.17** (as per screen shot below - some info removed for security reasons). So far it has our Network Admins a little perplexed. They have tried adding me to different trusted domain WAS groups, no luck. I also tried logging in from different browsers, flushing browser cache, running browsers like Chrome Incognito - all which probably has nothing to do with it, but no luck. Is this indeed related to inadequate security? If anyone has experienced this and has any suggestion it would be greatly appreciated. Please forgive me for any lack of information and if I have not explained this very well - I am just used to logging in and doing very specific tasks through the console, and that's it. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Your user probably have only `monitor` role. They need to add you or group that you belong to to the higher role e.g. operator or administrator, depending on what you really need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this IBM KnowledgeCenter topic](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rsec_adminroles.html), you'll need Operator role: "An individual or group that uses the operator role has monitor privileges plus ability to change the runtime state."

Comment: @F Rowe - Thank you to you and @Gas for your responses! I also apologize, as they did try adding me to a couple of groups - one with OPER in the name, which I would have presumed has Operator status? And the other group has ADMIN in the name, which I would have thought had a similar status? But given your responses, I will take this back to the security folks here. I am going to mark your responses as the answer because I believe you are correct. Thanks again!